# If exist then update in oracle forms 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a code block where record insert if record already exist then update
table. i am trying `If (sql%rowcount = 0) then` but it's not working in cursor and more one records.

What I tried so far as the code block is

```
declare
  remp_id     varchar2(60);
  remp_name   varchar2(100);
  rdesig      varchar2(100);
  rdept_no    number;
  rdesig_no   number;
  rdept_name  varchar2(60);
  cursor alfa is
    select emp_code, emp_name, desig, dept_name, dept_no, desig_no
      from emp
     where emp_code between :first_code and :second_code;
begin
  open alfa;
  loop
    fetch alfa
      into remp_id, remp_name, rdesig, rdept_name, rdept_no, rdesig_no;
    exit when alfa%notfound;
    update att_reg_mo
       set emp_code  = remp_id,
           emp_name  = remp_name,
           desig     = rdesig,
           dept_name = rdept_name,
           dept_no   = rdept_no,
           desig_no  = rdesig_no,
           att_date  = :att_date,
           emp_att   = :emp_att,
           att_type  = 'MA',
           reg_date  = :reg_date
     where emp_code between :first_code and :second_code
       and reg_date = :reg_date
       and att_date = :att_date;
    commit;
    if (sql%rowcount = 0) then
      insert into att_reg_mo
        (emp_code,
         emp_name,
         desig,
         dept_name,
         att_date,
         emp_att,
         att_type,
         reg_date,
         dept_no,
         desig_no)
      values
        (remp_id,
         remp_name,
         rdesig,
         rdept_name,
         :att_date,
         :emp_att,
         'MA',
         :reg_date,
         rdept_no,
         rdesig_no);
    end if;
    commit;
  end loop;
  close alfa;
end;
```

when i am fire the trigger then record is insert but where need to update record it's update with null values

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use something like that:

```
DECLARE
  cursor test is 
        select 1 as v from dual
        union 
        select 2 as v from dual;
  n_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
  for rec in test loop
  BEGIN
      select 1 into n_var from dual where rec.v=2;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Please Update Any Table');
      EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Please Insert Any Table');
  END;
  end loop;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Unexpected error');
END;
```

Comment: How can i use it in cursor ? I got Error 
' Error # 103
Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION' when expecting one of the following
(begin case declare and exit for goto if loop mod null....)'

Answer (score 0):

`SQL%attribute` always refers to the most recently run `SELECT` or `DML` statement. It refreshes as to start from **zero** after any of transaction statement such as `COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK` or `SAVEPOINT` is issued, for a session in which **AUTOCOMMIT** is presumed to be **OFF** *by default*. Therefore, you always get zero from `SQL%ROWCOUNT` which is just before the `INSERT` statement, and keeping inserting to the concerned table during every run of code block.

So, remove the **f i r s t** `COMMIT`, *removing also keeps the atomicity of the whole transaction*, from your code block.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fa7b64bec415da729cad429962c874bc)</kbd>